# Humble and boasting addresses in English

Tags: vocabulary

In Chinese, there are rich vocabularies for humble and boasting addresses for oneself, by 'address' I mean way to call oneself with an elevated or devalued status, kind of like 'your humble servant' in English. I wonder how to translate the following examples into English:

Humble address:

> 这是敝司的标书。

Literal translation: These are the bidding documents from my shabby employer.

When Chinese say it, it's the representative from one company presenting the documents to another company. "My shabby employer" is a way to call "the company I represent" with a degraded status in order to show respect to the other company. There is no disparagement or sarcasm in it.

Boasting address:

> 哥只是个传说。

It literally means '(Your) elder brother is just a legend'.

The real message is 'I, who you should look up to like an elder brother, is nothing special but a legend.' By calling oneself 'brother', the speaker is making an arrogant expression, or taunting the listener.

Comment: I think that 这是敝司的标书。and 哥只是个传说。come as close as one can get in English.

Comment: It's hard to understand what it is that you are looking for. What is your actual question?

Comment: @RaduMiron "what is the best way to express them in English"

Comment: There isn't a way to express them in English. English doesn't do this. That's what @EdwinAshworth was saying: the closest you will get is actually the Chinese.

Comment: @StJohnoftheCross I see. That's also the answer I am looking for.

Comment: Are you talking about sarcasm? 'I, who you should look up to like an elder brother, is nothing special but a legend.'

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr Not exactly; I am looking for ways in English (words/idioms, special sentence constructs, etc.) to achieve the same function as the humble/boasting address do in Chinese.

Comment: @NS.X. Why do the Chinese use these addresses; in what contexts?

Comment: I've read your question twice, and I have come to the conclusion that, nevermind the "humble" and "boasting" bits: I have absolutely no idea what you mean by "address". Your translation of the first bit of Chinese sounds like an attempt to disparage your employer, while the second one makes zero sense. I mean, absolutely none. English words, not an English sentence. To fix this, I think you need to, first of all, ask it at ell.stackexchange.com, and second of all, get a more competent English speaker to help you translate the Chinese.

Comment: I'm extremely curious - by "addresses", do you mean "titles" such as "my colleague", "my employer", etc., in other words, how you "address" a person?  What is confusing to us native speakers is that when you say "address", we're thinking of a physical location such as "123 Main St., Chicago, IL, USA"  Before this question is closed - can you please elaborate on what you mean by "address"?  Thanks! :-)

Comment: @Marthaª By address I mean an expression to call oneself, like "your humble servant". If "address" is not the right word, please correct me. The first translation is a just literal translation. When this sentence is used in Chinese, it's meant to be a modest expression (in front of another company) rather than disparagement or sarcasm. I will try ELL SE. Thanks.

Comment: @KristinaLopez Please see my intention of using "address" in the above comment and if it is indeed wrong, I would like to know the right word for it.

Comment: @KristinaLopez no it's not like a signature. I've updated my question trying to be more clear. One such 'address' is replacing I or We in a sentence.

Comment: @NS.X., I was confused by your use of "your humble servent".  That is used as a closing sometimes.  Given your definition, I would say I have never seen anything like that used in a CV or other formal writing.  I am used to seeing straight-forward language that is devoid of superfluous modifiers meant to boost up my employer or humble myself.  I know that there is much I don't know about other cultures but this would seem a bit anachronistic if I received a CV with that sort of style to the writing.  Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: @KristinaLopez None of this has anything to do with a CV. From which part of the question did you get that impression? I need to edit that part.

Comment: From Rajah9's answer.  I guess the bottom line is that your purpose is still unclear.  The type of document you're planning is integral to the style of language chosen.  Without explicit details, you'll get users trying vainly to help you through comments. Translation is off-topic and without more details, I think your question will either be too localized or will not be clear enough to help other users.

Comment: This seems related to the valediction form, “Your humble servant, _etc._, _etc._”—which might be as close as English gets to the form you’re asking about.

Answer (score 1):

While English has lost much of its class distinctions, one can express both self-abasing and prideful expressions.

If the employer on your CV were large and well known, then *my shabby employer* has a sense of irony. I think a *bidding document* would be called an *offer letter* in the US. (May I assume that the salary described is considered large and that the Chinese is again expressing irony?)

In translating into English, the irony would be lost. Unless it's a company that the reader would immediately recognize, it's better to state this without irony.

> Here is the offer letter from my Fortune 500 employer.
>
> IBM employed me right out of college.

It is better in English-speaking circles to not mention your salary. You would be giving up a valuable negotiation point. (Probably better to discuss this issue at http://workplace.stackexchange.com .)

The boasting address is much more direct in English. We lose the elder brother intermediary (because elder brother does not convey the same status in English.)

> Your exploits are legendary.
>
> You are a rock star.
>
> Superman ain't got nothin' on you.
>
> You are my hero.
> (If you say this with a sing-song or high-pitched voice, it will mean the opposite.)

I would only use the first in more formal settings. They are all idiomatic.

---

EDIT: Thank you for updating the boastful address. Something was lost in translation.

I'm rewriting your interpretation to:

> 'I, whom you should look up to as a superior elder brother, am extraordinary and a legend.'

(Please improve on the translation.)

A parallel English idiom is:

> Who's your daddy?

This [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who%27s_your_daddy?_%28phrase%29) says "It is commonly used as a boastful claim of dominance over the intended listener." An added parallel with the Chinese idiom is the use of the familial relationship (Chinese=elder brother, English=father).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry my question wasn't clear, I've updated it.

Comment: These are all semantically close translations, even though the register is very different (these are very informal and the OPs examples are very formal I think.) But culturally, in most (all?) English speaking cultures -nowadays-, one never says anything like this. If you used any of these, you'd come across as socially inept (outright boasts or defacement are avoided, but there is some leeway for subtle methods).

Comment: @Mitch Thanks! What you said is the key information I am missing and it actually answers the question.

Comment: +1 Great comment about register and culture, @Mitch. I don't think OP would use the boast in business settings. Similarly, I don't think English speakers would use "Who's your daddy" in business settings.